# DNS Resolution / Resolved not working on Fedora 35

Tags: fedora, dns, resolv.conf, systemd-resolved

DNS resolution has broken on my laptop, I'm running Fedora 35

The issue started occurring today, the machine wasn't used for several days and had died due to discharge (it might have been on linux at the time), I dual boot Win10 and networking is fine there... tried a hard reset and made sure windows shutdown without quick startup.

things which are working:

- `ping 1.1.1.1` or any IP
- Telegram

If I disable and mask `resolved` and modify `resolv.conf` to use `1.1.1.1` it works alright (how i am posting this)

All the below data is before i masked and disabled `resolv.conf` to post this

/etc/resolv.conf:

```
# This is /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf managed by man:systemd-resolved(8).
# Do not edit.
#
# This file might be symlinked as /etc/resolv.conf. If you're looking at
# /etc/resolv.conf and seeing this text, you have followed the symlink.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs should typically not access this file directly, but only
# through the symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a
# different way, replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .
```

`resolvectl status`:

```
sids@uss-enterprise ~> resolvectl status
Global
       Protocols: LLMNR=resolve -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (eno1)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 3 (wlp4s0)
Current Scopes: LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 4 (ipv6leakintrf0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: ::1
       DNS Servers: ::1
        DNS Domain: ~.
```

`systemd-resolved` service status:

```
sids@uss-enterprise ~> sudo systemctl status systemd-resolved
● systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-11-19 20:53:32 IST; 20s ago
       Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
             man:org.freedesktop.resolve1(5)
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network-configuration-managers
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver-clients
   Main PID: 3695 (systemd-resolve)
     Status: "Processing requests..."
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18842)
     Memory: 8.4M
        CPU: 89ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-resolved.service
             └─3695 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-resolved

Nov 19 20:53:32 uss-enterprise systemd-resolved[3695]: Got message type=method_return sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.172 path=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=4294967295 reply_cookie=29 signature=u>
Nov 19 20:53:32 uss-enterprise systemd-resolved[3695]: D-Bus LLMNR change request from client PID 1168 (n/a) with UID 4294967295
Nov 19 20:53:32 uss-enterprise systemd-resolved[3695]: Sent message type=method_return sender=n/a destination=:1.23 path=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=30 reply_cookie=1545 signature=n/a error-name=n/a error>
Nov 19 20:53:32 uss-enterprise systemd-resolved[3695]: Got message type=method_call sender=:1.23 destination=:1.172 path=/org/freedesktop/resolve1 interface=org.freedesktop.resolve1.Manager member=SetLinkDNS cook>
Nov 19 20:53:32 uss-enterprise systemd-resolved[3695]: Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.DBus path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=GetConnectionUnixU>
Nov 19 20:53:32 uss-enterprise systemd-resolved[3695]: Got message type=method_return sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.172 path=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=4294967295 reply_cookie=31 signature=u>
Nov 19 20:53:32 uss-enterprise systemd-resolved[3695]: Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.DBus path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=GetConnectionUnixP>
Nov 19 20:53:32 uss-enterprise systemd-resolved[3695]: Got message type=method_return sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.172 path=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=4294967295 reply_cookie=32 signature=u>
Nov 19 20:53:32 uss-enterprise systemd-resolved[3695]: D-Bus DNS server change request from client PID 1168 (n/a) with UID 4294967295
Nov 19 20:53:32 uss-enterprise systemd-resolved[3695]: Sent message type=method_return sender=n/a destination=:1.23 path=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=33 reply_cookie=1546 signature=n/a error-name=n/a error>
```

the override given to resolved:

```
[Service]
Environment=SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

log level of resolved:

```
sids@uss-enterprise ~> sudo systemctl service-log-level systemd-resolved
debug
```

the curious part is i don't see any log (even the ones i can see in `systemctl status`) in `journalctl`:

```
sids@uss-enterprise ~> sudo journalctl -u systemd-resolved -f
-- Journal begins at Sun 2021-10-31 18:01:42 IST. --
Nov 21 20:39:41 uss-enterprise systemd-resolved[1119]: proton0: Bus client set DNS server list to: 10.18.0.1
Nov 21 20:39:41 uss-enterprise systemd-resolved[1119]: ipv6leakintrf0: Bus client set default route setting: no
Nov 21 22:10:41 uss-enterprise systemd-resolved[1119]: ipv6leakintrf0: Bus client set search domain list to: ~.
Nov 21 22:10:41 uss-enterprise systemd-resolved[1119]: ipv6leakintrf0: Bus client set default route setting: yes
Nov 21 22:10:41 uss-enterprise systemd-resolved[1119]: ipv6leakintrf0: Bus client set DNS server list to: ::1
Nov 21 22:10:41 uss-enterprise systemd-resolved[1119]: proton0: Bus client reset search domain list.
Nov 21 22:10:41 uss-enterprise systemd-resolved[1119]: proton0: Bus client set default route setting: no
Nov 21 22:10:41 uss-enterprise systemd-resolved[1119]: proton0: Bus client reset DNS server list.
Nov 25 00:32:28 uss-enterprise systemd-resolved[1119]: Clock change detected. Flushing caches.
Nov 25 00:53:08 uss-enterprise systemd-resolved[1119]: Clock change detected. Flushing caches.
```

some attempts to resolve dns using `dig`:
192.168.22.215 is the gateway of my router

```
sids@uss-enterprise ~> dig @192.168.22.215 fedoraproject.org

; <<>> DiG 9.16.23-RH <<>> @192.168.22.215 fedoraproject.org
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 44291
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 6, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;fedoraproject.org.     IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
fedoraproject.org.  55  IN  A   13.250.126.156
fedoraproject.org.  55  IN  A   13.212.21.54
fedoraproject.org.  55  IN  A   13.233.183.170
fedoraproject.org.  55  IN  A   38.145.60.21
fedoraproject.org.  55  IN  A   38.145.60.20
fedoraproject.org.  55  IN  A   13.125.120.8

;; Query time: 7 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.22.215#53(192.168.22.215)
;; WHEN: Fri Nov 19 21:00:15 IST 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 131
```

`dig` with 127.0.0.53:

```
sids@uss-enterprise ~> dig @127.0.0.53 fedoraproject.org

; <<>> DiG 9.16.23-RH <<>> @127.0.0.53 fedoraproject.org
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

EDIT:

`/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`:

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
#  terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by the Free
#  Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option)
#  any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults. Local configuration
# should be created by either modifying this file, or by creating "drop-ins" in
# the resolved.conf.d/ subdirectory. The latter is generally recommended.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file and all drop-ins.
#
# Use 'systemd-analyze cat-config systemd/resolved.conf' to display the full config.
#
# See resolved.conf(5) for details.

[Resolve]
# Some examples of DNS servers which may be used for DNS= and FallbackDNS=:
# Cloudflare: 1.1.1.1#cloudflare-dns.com 1.0.0.1#cloudflare-dns.com 2606:4700:4700::1111#cloudflare-dns.com 2606:4700:4700::1001#cloudflare-dns.com
# Google:     8.8.8.8#dns.google 8.8.4.4#dns.google 2001:4860:4860::8888#dns.google 2001:4860:4860::8844#dns.google
# Quad9:      9.9.9.9#dns.quad9.net 149.112.112.112#dns.quad9.net 2620:fe::fe#dns.quad9.net 2620:fe::9#dns.quad9.net
# DNS=1.1.1.1
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSOverTLS=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#LLMNR=resolve
#Cache=yes
#CacheFromLocalhost=no
#DNSStubListener=yes
#DNSStubListenerExtra=
#ReadEtcHosts=yes
#ResolveUnicastSingleLabel=no
```

`dig` with `127.0.0.1`:

```
dig @127.0.0.1 fedoraproject.org

; <<>> DiG 9.16.23-RH <<>> @127.0.0.1 fedoraproject.org
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

nmap on `127.0.0.53`

```
sids@uss-enterprise ~ [9]> sudo nmap -sU 127.0.0.53 -p 53
[sudo] password for sids: 
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-11-26 01:06 IST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.53)
Host is up.

PORT   STATE         SERVICE
53/udp open|filtered domain

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.11 seconds
```

nmap on `127.0.0.1`:

```
sids@uss-enterprise ~> sudo nmap -sU 127.0.0.1 -p 53
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-11-26 01:06 IST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000042s latency).

PORT   STATE  SERVICE
53/udp closed domain

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.07 seconds
```

`/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` is symlinked to `/etc/resolv.conf` see above

`/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`:

```
# This is /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf managed by man:systemd-resolved(8).
# Do not edit.
#
# This file might be symlinked as /etc/resolv.conf. If you're looking at
# /etc/resolv.conf and seeing this text, you have followed the symlink.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients directly to
# all known uplink DNS servers. This file lists all configured search domains.
#
# Third party programs should typically not access this file directly, but only
# through the symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a
# different way, replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver ::1
search .
```

Comment: DNS is resolving domain names to IPs, i. e. doing a `nslookup duckduckgo.com` will give you something like `Address: 40.114.177.156`. Executing a `dig`, `nmap` or `ping` to an IP like 127.0.0.1 or 192.x.x.x won't require a DNS resolve to an IP, use a domain name for testing.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it!

It was a broken VPN setup, remember I mentioned the device got discharged while on Linux?

A VPN connection was active at the time and it was doing DNS Leak protection so it had configured a virtual network interface to resolve DNS

That network was still active after reboot, but VPN wasn't running so everything was getting dropped

Started the VPN and it started working, after I turned off the VPN it disconnected the virtual network and resorted full resolved functionality.

Dropping this here in case someone else finds it useful

Comment: I had exactly the same issue. VPN left a dummy connection that caused domain resolution to fail. Deleted the connection and works now. Documentation I was following (Fedora in my case) - https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Networking/CLI#Delete_a_connection_configuration